# The group of real cube roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, radicals

Let $\sqrt[3]{a}$ indicate the real cube root of a number $a \in \Bbb{R}$.

Then the set of all cube roots forms a group under $\sqrt[3]{a} \oplus \sqrt[3]{b} = \sqrt[3]{a^3 + b^3}$.  This group is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb{R}, +)$ I don't think.

What is the significance of this group?

Comment: Something is not right, what is the neutral element?

Comment: @orangeskid the neutral element is $0$.

Comment: just say that he means real cube root, not positive real cube root

Comment: The set of real cube roots of real numbers is exactly $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @lhf, yes but are the structures the same?

Comment: Doesn't check the definition

Comment: Is your operation $(a,b)\mapsto \sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}$ or is it $(a,b)\mapsto\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}$?  These are not the same operation...

Comment: @Eric $\sqrt[3]{a} \oplus \sqrt[3]{b} \equiv \sqrt[3]{a^3 + b^3}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This operation is not a group operation, since it is not associative.  For instance, $$1\oplus (1\oplus -1)=1\oplus0=1$$ is different from $$(1\oplus 1)\oplus -1=\sqrt[3]{2}\oplus -1=\sqrt[3]{7}.$$

This operation is much easier to think about if you ignore the cube roots and write it as $a\oplus b=a^3+b^3$ (which gives an isomorphic structure, since taking cube roots is a bijection).  This makes it more obvious why you should not expect it to be associative, or very nice algebraically at all.